# Modifying the String, Date and Number object in JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, extension-methods

I'm working on a project which makes heavy use of extension methods to convert strings from the UI-layer into their appropriate object-types in the code-layer: *(pseudo-code)*

```
// C#

/*
Converts a String from the UI-layer, formatted according to a user-defined
UI-culture preference (in this case from da-DK) into a Double
*/

Double d = "1.000,50".fromWebStringToDouble(); // 1000.5
```

To unify the programming experience across C# and JavaScript, I want to modify the prototypes of the `String`, `Date` and `Number` object in JavaScript, to implement similar functionality.

Question is: Is this a good idea? We all know that modifying `Array`'s prototype seriously cripples the object. But does this horror-scenario apply to the `String`, `Date` and `Number` object?

Comment: Have you got some reference for Array being crippled by adding items to its prototype, first I've heard of this?

Comment: @Anthony : see http://www.prototypejs.org/api/array ; it's not "crippled", in my opinion ; it's just that you shouldn't use "for ... in".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like the way prototype adds methodes to those objects, so, for me, if a **Framework** is doing that, it's OK.

Still, it seems more risky to do so in an application :

- when using a Framework, you are expecting people to know how it works
- when developping an application, and adding random methods to Objects, you can't expect people to know all about those -- especially if there is no good documentation about it.

So, in your case, I would only go with that idea if two conditions are met :

- you are doing this in some kind of Framework, that is common to the whole project (and not in a JS file specific to one or two pages)
- there is documentation about methods that are added, what they do, and how to use them.

Comment: Conditions are met. Thanks Pascal :)

Comment: If conditions are met, that's fine by me ^^ You're welcome :-) Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

[The Prototype Library](http://prototypejs.org) gets away with it. The big issues have been with the Array prototype (people mistakenly thinking Prototype breaks their `for..in` loops [it doesn't; they were [already broken](http://proto-scripty.wikidot.com/prototype:tip-looping-through-arrays) ;-) ]) and with Element prototypes, which are a cross-browser problem. Since you're not talking about doing those, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've added a bunch of features to String, Date, Number and even Array via prototype .  Can't say that I've experienced any issues with do this.  Just avoid doing such a thing to Object that will cause hassle.